# What is the common practice to write comment that means "do nothing" in Java?

Tags: java, exception, comments

I have next code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
// do something
try {
    is.close();
} catch(IOException ex) {
    // do nothing
    // or
    // NOP
    // or something else?
}
```

The question is is there any convention in Java world for comment that tells do nothing? Like in my case I want to do nothing if it is not possible to close InputStream.
Is the "NOP" comment acceptable? It is from Assembler and it means "no operation".

Comment: I find both variants equally readable, but in this instance I personally would write `// ignore the exception`.

Comment: `} catch(IOException ignoreAndContinue) {`

Comment: errr.......why do you want to *ignore* exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
try {
    ...
} catch (IOException ignored) {}
```

is complete, clear and succinct.

---

But you should be using something like [Apache Commons IO `IOUtils.closeQuietly(InputStream)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29).

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really matter, there's no defined convention though I see NOP more often than others.  For me the important thing is marking *why* you are ignoring the exception.  I personally prefer a "//NOP - Explanation" style e.g.

```
//NOP - If we can't read this input file it doesn't matter as next block will try another
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way of doing it, there isn't even a standard that says you have to put a comment there. If at all there would be a guideline, it would be in your company's coding standards. If not, use whatever you like.

Only 1 thing i can say about it.
Make sure it's clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

There is no convention that I know of. I usually put // pass, for the python statement.